# How do I copy files from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I need to copy a file from one directory to another and at the same time, change the file extension. How do I do this?

Comment: 13 questions, all basic/vague and none of them have been accepted. Good chance that you are unlikely to get any good response.

Comment: You need to learn to generalize your knowledge. Some of the questions you ask are minor variations that can have general principles applied to deal with those variations. People here are very much willing to help with basic questions, but you need to show that you are applying some effort on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
copy "dir\subdir\filetocopy.ext1" "dir\newdir\filetobecopiedto.ext2"
```

Comment: sathya, have you not figured out I have just started working with computers in cli format. I'm trying to adjust to this sight and how to ask questions. I am a beginner at best so tr to take that into consideration when being critical or just don't respond.